# App removed from whitelist in Stamina mode (Sony devices)

Tags: android, sony

Some Sony devices have a Stamina mode to increase the standby time of the device. It turns off 
data traffic and prevents background activities from waking up the system. Apps can be white-listed though.
Some users have reported that my app is removed from the white list after each reboot which is bad because it's an email client that should be able to wake up the system when new mails are pushed.
Does anyone have more in-depth information about the Stamina mode and why it would remove apps from the white list?
My online research didn't bring up anything useful on this.
There are a couple of articles about the mode but they don't go any further than explaining what the mode does and how it can be configured. The best I could come up with was this: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/03/08/warning-xperia-z-stamina-alarmmanager.html but that doesn't answer my question either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After purchasing a Sony Xperia Z and doing some extensive tests I finally found the offending "component" ... the package name!

I created the most basic test app with one Activity (doing nothing), one app icon, one string  for the app name and the manifest file. I installed the app with two different package names (from two of my apps):

1. package="com.onegravity.sudoku4ever.free"
2. package="com.onegravity.sudoku.sudoku10kfree"

I then added both apps to the white list, rebooted the device and the second app disappeared from the white list. The app is also removed from the white list if it's the only one installed (If I install only the test app with package name com.onegravity.sudoku.sudoku10kfree).

I didn't run any further tests to find out which package names "make it" because the package name is the one thing I can't change in my apps.

Obviously there's a major bug in the stamina mode / white list component and only Sony can fix it ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can tell you that on an SONY Xperia Z, with the latest firmware, I cannot reproduce the problem. Apps added to the STAMINA whitelist survive a reboot.

Beyond that, I suspect that you will need to [contact SONY](http://developer.sonymobile.com/).

Comment: Usually apps stay on the whitelist after a reboot but mine doesn't seem to (sometimes anyway). I tested it on an Xperia Z, can't reproduce the issue but at least two users have reported the same now including screen shots of the whitelist before and after the reboot.
Anyway thanks for your answer, I might dig a little deeper if more users come up with this.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: Did the users say which specific SONY models they are using?

Comment: One says Xperia Z and the other one has the issue on a Zperia Z Ultra and a Zperia ZR

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: Well, at least for the Xperia Z user, make sure that they are on the latest firmware, as perhaps this was a bug that was fixed. I do not have either of those other devices.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The user with the Xperia Z replied:
"It's Android 4.2.2. Sony Update Center shows that my device has all the latest versions.". Any chance you can test it on your device? I know it's a lot to ask for but well I can try ;-).

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: Like I wrote originally, I have already tried rebooting a device, with one of my apps added to the whitelist, and it was on the whitelist after the reboot. If I understand your first comment correctly, you are seeing the same thing.

Comment: I know it works with your app but it might not work with my app as the user complaints indicate. My tests were not 100% conclusive because I had a device without Internet connectivity (I used one of Perfecto Mobile's devices which was unfortunately not connected). So the real test would be to have at least one email account setup as I suspect that the removal from the white list has something to do with how the app does the wake up.

Comment: There might even be a difference between POP3 and IMAP accounts. While one will be polled on a scheduled basis the other one will be pushed (if the email provider supports IMAP Idle). So the test might even be to have a POP3 and an IMAP Idle capable email account setup.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: For that level of analysis, I would recommend that you try to reach out to SONY.

Comment: BTW if you decide to continue working on your rich text editor I might be able to assist. I just finished mine and I might have some tricks up my sleeve that could help like allowing copy/paste selection AND using LinkSpans (usually one or the other works but not both), implementing NumberSpans (numbering of paragraphs), undo/redo and more.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin: I was planning on rebooting that project in a few weeks. Is yours open source?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40388/discussion-between-emanuel-moecklin-and-commonsware)

Comment: Sony doesn't respond to any form of contact. Developer support seems to be non-existing.

Comment: @CommonsWare what is the impact of stamina mode on accessibility services? Will they start working again after screen on?

Comment: @venkat: I have not dealt with STAMINA mode in a while, and I have never implemented an accessibility service. Unless SONY screwed up, though, an accessibility service should not be affected by STAMINA mode.